Cleaning up Cursors without Spaghetti and Duplicate Code?
I am using GoTo for Closing and Deallocating the Cursor.   Is there a better way to write my code?  Note, this code is for learning how to use Cursors and output Parameters.
I am new to TSQL, so feel free to comment on other items.  For example, I was looking for a stored Procedure that will close a Cursor if it is Open but I didn't find anything via Google Search.
Thank you
-- Find the MAX, MIN, Avg for each Color in the Products table using Cursor

USE [AdventureWorks2019]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[WithCursor]    Script Date: 5/29/2024 11:30:17 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER     PROC [dbo].[WithCursor]
(
    @color VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @MinStock INT OUTPUT,
    @MaxStock INT OUTPUT,
    @AvgStock INT OUTPUT
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRY
    
    Declare @recordCount int = ( SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM Production.Product 
        WHERE (@color IS NULL AND Color IS NULL) OR (Color = @color))

    -- ******************** NO Records Exist ********************
    IF @recordCount = 0
    Begin

        DECLARE @errorMessage NVARCHAR(200);
        IF @color IS NULL
            SET @errorMessage = N'There are no products with the color NULL';
        ELSE
            SET @errorMessage = CONCAT(N'There are no products with the color ', @color);

        RAISERROR(@errorMessage, 11, 1);
        RETURN -2; -- no such color

    End

    -- ******************** Open the Cursor for Products ********************
    DECLARE @level int;
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(0) 
        WHERE name = 'pCursor'
    )
    BEGIN
        CLOSE pCursor
        DEALLOCATE ProductCursor;
    END

    DECLARE pCursor CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT SafetyStockLevel
            FROM Production.Product
            WHERE (@color IS NULL AND Color IS NULL) OR (Color = @color);
        
    --Open the Cursor.  We know there is at least 1 record from the above check.
    OPEN pCursor  
    FETCH NEXT FROM pCursor INTO @level

    -- ******************** 1 Record Exist ********************
    IF @recordCount = 1
    Begin

        Set @MinStock = @level
        Set @MaxStock = @level
        Set @AvgStock = @level

        GoTo Cleanup

    End
    -- ******************** 2 or More Records Exist ********************
    
    Declare @SumLevel int
    Declare @MinLevel int
    Declare @MaxLevel int

    Set @SumLevel = @level
    Set @MinLevel = @level
    Set @MaxLevel = @level

    --Move to the second record
    FETCH NEXT FROM pCursor  INTO @level

    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
        
        Set @SumLevel = @SumLevel + @level

        If @level < @MinLevel
            Set @MinLevel = @level

        If @level > @MaxLevel
            Set @MaxLevel = @level

        FETCH NEXT FROM pCursor  INTO @level
    End
        
    
    Set @MinStock = @Minlevel
    Set @MaxStock = @Maxlevel
    Set @AvgStock = @SumLevel / @recordCount
    
   GoTo Cleanup

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
    
    --Cleanup
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(0) 
        WHERE name = 'pCursor'
    )
    BEGIN
        CLOSE pCursor
        DEALLOCATE ProductCursor;
    END
    
    RETURN -1;
END CATCH;

--Success
Cleanup:
CLOSE pCursor
DEALLOCATE pCursor
Return 0

I can duplicate the code and that will remove the GoTo but I am trying not to Duplicate code as much as possible.

You might want to ask your question in Code Review Stack Exchange instead

Random tips: (@color IS NULL AND Color IS NULL) OR (Color = @color) could be @color is not distinct from Color in SQL Server 2022. N'There are no products with the color ' + Coalesce( @color, N'NULL' ). Add statement terminators (;).

My thoughts: (1) I would drop the initial @RowCount calculation and the initial stand-alone FETCH NEXT. Just loop through the rows one-at-a-time, counting the occurrences. After the loop, if the count is zero, then take special action. (2) I never bother to check for and deallocate an existing cursor up front. I just assume the system is in a clean state to start. (Exception may be when debugging and selectively executing code fragments.) (3) If you catch an exception, perhaps you can just set a flag, drop through to cleanup logic, and finally take the appropriate return-result action.

If ProductCursor supposed to be different from pCursor?

Thank you for everyone's responses.
blurfus:  is there a way to automatically transfer this tread to Code Review?
Habo: Thank you.  Unfortunately, I am using SQL Server 2019 but I incorporated N'There are no products with the color ' + Coalesce( @color, N'NULL' ).
TN: Thanks for the ProductCursor point.  How come SQL Server didn't create an error? I am going to think more about your other points.

I posted a solution below.
In the Catch block when I Throw before the Return -1 the Return is not executed and vice versa.  What is the best practice for the location of the Throw?
Thank you

Per the DEALLOCATE documentation, "A cursor variable does not have to be explicitly deallocated. The variable is implicitly deallocated when it goes out of scope."  So maybe the answer is to apply the KISS Principle and not worry about cursor cleanup when exiting due to an error. (fiddle)

@TN I'm pretty sure they're only referring to the DECLARE @c CURSOR form, and not DECLARE c CURSOR form, but arguably it could be worded better.

@testing-ma-lady - Good catch. You are correct. I didn't spot the distinction between "cursor" and "cursor variable".  Still, something tricky is going on with the throw logic. If I comment out the close/deallocate cursor statements, the cursor remains after normal exit, but disappears after a re-THROW that is caught by the caller. See this fiddle. For the 3rd and 4th (ultraviolet and black) tests, the cursor disappears between "Here 2b" and "Here 3a", and I don't understand why. (That's when I searched and ran across that "implicitly deallocated" statement.)

I refactored the code with everyone's suggestions. Thank you everyone.  It was very helpful to read your feedback.  Going forward I will use Local Cursors.
    USE [AdventureWorks2019];
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[WithCursor]    Script Date: 5/29/2024 11:30:17 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC [dbo].[WithCursor]
(
    @color VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @MinStock INT OUTPUT,
    @MaxStock INT OUTPUT,
    @AvgStock INT OUTPUT
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY

    -- ******************** Open the Cursor for Products ********************

    DECLARE @level INT;

    --Local Cursor doesn't need to be deallocated
    DECLARE @pCursor CURSOR;

    SET @pCursor = CURSOR READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
      FOR 
        SELECT SafetyStockLevel
          FROM Production.Product
         WHERE Color = @color OR (@Color IS NULL AND Color IS NULL);

    -- Open the Cursor. 
    OPEN @pCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @pCursor INTO @level;

    -- ******************** Empty Recordset ********************
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @errorMessage NVARCHAR(200);
        SET @errorMessage = N'There are no products with the color ' + COALESCE(@color, N'NULL');
        RAISERROR(@errorMessage, 11, 1);
        RETURN -2; -- no such color
    END;

    -- ******************** 1 or More Records Exist ********************

    DECLARE @SumLevel INT = 0;
    DECLARE @MinLevel INT = @level;
    DECLARE @MaxLevel INT = @level;
    DECLARE @recordCount INT = 0;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SumLevel = @SumLevel + @level;

        IF @level < @MinLevel
            SET @MinLevel = @level;

        IF @level > @MaxLevel
            SET @MaxLevel = @level;

        FETCH NEXT FROM @pCursor INTO @level;

        SET @recordCount = @recordCount + 1;
    END;

    --Set the Output Parameters
    SET @MinStock = @MinLevel;
    SET @MaxStock = @MaxLevel;
    SET @AvgStock = @SumLevel / @recordCount;


END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    THROW;
    RETURN -1;

END CATCH;


Also be aware of the differences between LOCAL and GLOBAL cursors. Typically, you'd want to use a LOCAL cursor, to avoid errors like: "A cursor with the name 'YourCursorName' already exists". If you don't explicitly specify, typically it will default to GLOBAL (depends on database options).

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
